# Diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory

Some time ago I encountered in my work the following equation
$ cos(\frac{2 \pi k}{l}  )= B$

The problem consists in finding for a given  irrational number $B$, a pair of integers $(k,l)$ satisfying the written equation.

Comment: This is, of course, not a diophantine equation.  Also:  $A$ serves no purpose here, right?

Comment: Yes you are right. I firstly shouldn't have called it "diophantine" . It is also true that $A$ has no purpose.

Answer (score 3):

This is about to be closed as "unclear what you're asking", perhaps I misunderstood the question, but it seems you ask for a characterization of the rational angles $\alpha=2\pi k/l$ that produce an irrational cosine.

This question is addressed by Jörg Jahnel in these [notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2938), see in particular section 6: $\cos\alpha$ is an algebraic number of degree $d>1$ if and only if the Euler function $\phi(l)=2d$. For example, a quintic irrationality is obtained only for angles $\alpha/2\pi=1/22$ or $5/22$.

Comment: Even though you understood what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: @user38651 Was that really your question? One possible interpretation of what you wrote was that you were given $B$ somehow and and wanted to know if the $k,l$ existed. For most $B$ it doesn't.